# Open database with public art?

Tags: space

I’m looking for an open database of art in public space.

I’m aware of a few localized initiatives, with different levels of openness, but is there an open database that aims to collect all art in public space?

Comment: I vaguely remember (no source sorry) that someone tried to create a site with the Louvre's art and the Louvre sued to have the site closed claiming some of the works are copyrighted, so creating such a database may be a nontrivial legal issue. The current conditions (https://www.louvre.fr/en/conditions-use-images) suggest that some images can be used for non-commercial purposes.

Comment: Thanks. Though, I'm looking for a database of art in public space, which I would think make it easier to not invoke copyright issues.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across sites like [publicartarchive.org](https://www.publicartarchive.org/).

But I believe you may need to use a search engine like google to find country specific ones and aggregate data.

Also see [this previous answer](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4250/public-domain-paintings-database) that can help in retrieving data.

Comment: That's an excellent start. A pity they don't have an API. And no clear way of contributing to the content.

Comment: See this link for how to contribute: https://www.publicartarchive.org/content/guide

Comment: It appears publicartarchive.org has died a quiet death.